# Missing required parameters in my route in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, uri

**I have this problem with url with multiple parameters please help me.**

```
Route::get('export/{start}/{end}',[App\Http\Controllers\ExportController::class, 'export'])->name('export');
```

> And this is my controller

```
public function export(Request $request,$start = 0,$end = 0)
    {
      return Excel::download(new ExportAttendance(strval($start),strval($end)),'Attendance.xlsx');
}
```

Comment: where are you using this route?? add details to the question to get help.. and there are a lot of similar questions already here in so. did you try anything??

Answer (score 0):

You will use code like this

```
   $url = route('export', ['start' => '2021-05-22', 'end' => '2021-06-22']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can I converted it to url that I post?